# .mim file not being shown on ibus-m17n language list

Tags: 20.04, ibus

I have written my own IBUS table in a .mim file, and copied it to /usr/share/m17n

Unfortunately, it doesn't show up on the language list.

I based it on an already existing and working mim file, and it was working until Kubuntu 19.10 (even then, it refused to work for a long time, and then suddenly showed up)

I have checked the permissions

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6176 Apr 25 10:41 si-ralla.mim
```

and it is the same as the ones that work.

I am at my wit's end right now. Does anyone have any ideas on what's wrong, or a way I can debug this to find where I am screwing up?

Thank you.

** EDIT **
Literally 15 minutes later

After writing this post, I opened the file as root, and deleted all the multiple tabs between the string and the comment, and it worked!

All of a sudden, it showed up.

And now I am left wondering what it was that did that?

Was it the removing of the multiple tabs? But there are many .mim files that have multiple tabs in them

Was it writing it as root? But all writing as root does, is change the ownerships and permissions to what they were already.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have what seems to be the identical issue in Linux Mint 20 (derived from Ubuntu 20.04). I've provided details at https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=334843, but it's essentially the same as Suchetha describes: .mim files and corresponding icons for scripts/languages that I've used for years on Ubuntu and Mint are still present in /usr/share/m17n, but only some of them appear as choices when adding input methods.

In my case, m17n:ar:kbd, m17n:el:kbd, m17n:he:kbd, and m17n:ko:han2 (Arabic, Greek, Hebrew, and Korean) don't appear as selections, although m17n:hi:inscript, m17n:fa:isiri, m17n:th:tis820 and m17n:ur:phonetic (Hindi, Farsi, Thai, and Urdu) still appear and function normally. I'll reiterate here that I've used all of these in versions earlier than 20.04 with no issues.

Unlike Suchetha's experience, however, opening and saving any of the relevant .mim files has made no difference for me (also, like the OP, I can't imagine why changes in tabs/white space within the .mim files would affect anything).

Any ideas or suggested things to explore would be welcome. Thanks.